# How to align uicollectionviewcell? swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How to align uicollectionviewcell? swift

without  https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

How pictured

[image]

Comment: What do you wean by "align"?  Like a grid/table?

Comment: are u using autolayout?

Comment: You have a code snippet?

Comment: hi, you can you autosize cell refer link: https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios8-day-by-day-day-37-autosizing-collection-view-cells

Comment: @kdbanman this collection. Now it is "incorrect"

Comment: @casillas yes, using